# Why not directly brute force sparsify the OLS estimator instead of using Lasso?

Tags: least-squares, lasso, sparse

I have a question about the Lasso estimator. I understand that it is particularly useful in high-dimensional settings due to its sparsity-inducing properties.

For instance, if the design matrix is orthogonal, it is known that applying Lasso is essentially equivalent to performing Ordinary Least Squares (OLS). In this case, one sets to zero all components of the OLS estimator that fall below a certain threshold and finally introduces a slight bias to the remaining components.

However, why can't this strategy be used in the non-orthogonal case? In this scenario, could we not simply perform OLS and then zero out all components of the OLS estimator that are not sufficiently large?

From an intuitive perspective, if a component of the OLS estimator is small, it suggests that the corresponding covariate is not particularly influential. Hence, it seems reasonable to set it equal to zero.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that your intuition is incorrect.  Nonorthogonality is equivalent to being unable to assign at least some parameters ("component of the OLS estimator") uniquely to an explanatory variable.  One way to develop a better intuition is to study such situations closely.  Another is to study the implications of the OLS equations.  You can find [many posts here on CV with such material](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=multiple%20regression%20significan*&searchOn=3). Other searches for "interaction," "mediation," "moderation," and "multicollinearity" will help too.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment, I have understood what I was missing.

Comment: Also, and separately from @whuber's point, sparsifying the OLS estimator is *not actually easier or faster* than doing lasso.

Comment: Thresholding can be a great idea, just not necessarily to OLS; see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.08071.pdf

Comment: Interesting remarks, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, LASSO lets you pick a value for small based on cross validation.

Second, LASSO does that adjustment.

Simply dropping a variable will result in a big bias.

[Statology](https://www.statology.org/lasso-regression-in-r/) offers a nice example using the `mtcars` data.

```r
set.seed(1234)

#Start of statology code
y <- mtcars$hp

#define matrix of predictor variables
x <- data.matrix(mtcars[, c('mpg', 'wt', 'drat', 'qsec')])

install.packages("glmnet")
library(glmnet)

#perform k-fold cross-validation to find optimal lambda value
cv_model <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1)

#find optimal lambda value that minimizes test MSE
best_lambda <- cv_model$lambda.min
best_lambda

#produce plot of test MSE by lambda value
plot(cv_model) 

best_model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, lambda = best_lambda)
coef(best_model)

#end of statology code  
m1 <- lm(y~x)
m1
```

The coefficients through LASSO were

```r
(Intercept) 477.905338
mpg          -3.102593
wt           19.252832
drat          .       
qsec        -18.534966
```

Through `lm`:

```r
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  473.779    105.213   4.503 0.000116 ***
xmpg          -2.877      2.381  -1.209 0.237319    
xwt           26.037     13.514   1.927 0.064600 .  
xdrat          4.819     15.952   0.302 0.764910    
xqsec        -20.751      3.993  -5.197 1.79e-05 ***
```

Note that 1) The coef for `drat` is the smallest in terms of absolute value of t. 2) Since the mean of `drat` is 3.60, if you just drop `drat` you will be deducting an average of $4.81\cdot3.60 = 17.4$ from each predicted value. 3) LASSO adjusts the other coefficients by fairly substantial amounts, but it does not adjust the intercept by much.

Of course, you could run

```r
x2 <- data.matrix(mtcars[, c('mpg', 'wt',  'qsec')])
m2 <- lm(y~x2)
m2
```

which gives

```r
 (Intercept)        x2mpg         x2wt       x2qsec  
     494.57        -2.70        25.04       -20.97
```

which is quite different from the LASSO results.

Comment: Thank you for the nice example, it helped me to build intuition and understand the problem.